# Targeting minimal Android API level from Kotlin JVM project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a Kotlin library that I devlopped for and used in a server application (JRE 8) but now I need to use it on an android app with a specific minSdkVersion, let assume minSdkVersion:15. How can I insure that my lib is compatible ?
Is there any compiler options to set to insure Android compliance ?
My library is built with Maven and for the moment I have set some properties:

```
<properties>
<kotlin.version>1.2.71</kotlin.version>
<maven.compiler>3.5.1</maven.compiler>
<kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.6</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
<maven-compiler-plugin.source>1.7</maven-compiler-plugin.source>
<maven-compiler-plugin.target>1.7</maven-compiler-plugin.target>
</properties>
```

But I’m sure if it’s the enough ?

UPDATE: 
Even with maven target set to 1.7 I get an error on Android API level 21 :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method asPredicate()Ljava/util/function/Predicate; in class Ljava/util/regex/Pattern; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.regex.Pattern' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

Comment: If your library has no Android SDK references, it is compatible with all Android SDK versions.

Comment: No it does not work this way. for example if I use  java.util.regex.Pattern#asPredicate I'll get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method asPredicate .... when I run on a device with Android 5

Comment: That depends on what JDK you're using. I recommend you use JDK 7 or lower.

Comment: I'm using JDK7 since I have specified in my pom.xml: <maven-compiler-plugin.source>1.7</maven-compiler-plugin.source>

Comment: But there's no such method java.util.regex.Pattern#asPredicate in JDK 7 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Yes, but I don't now why maven is compiling correctly my source code. BTW all my code is written in Kotlin

Comment: In any case you cannot use `Pattern#asPredicate` in Android, so you have to remove that.